# Override Ajax success

Tags: javascript

Thank you for reading.

Basically, what I want to do is override the ajax success event.

In most guides and questions here that I have come across seem to only address adding a callback to the success event. I want to actually override the event itself.

Essentially, I need to be able to catch the success event before $.ajax does and run my logic prior to the ajax event receiving the data.

What I currently have is this but it seems that altering values in the 'this' context does nothing.

```
var XMLHttpRequestSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(){
    var onError = this.onerror;
    var onLoad = this.onload;

    this.onload = (function(){
        this.response = "new response";
        return onLoad.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
    });

    return XMLHttpRequestSend.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `$.ajax` - ahhh, jQuery ... it probably doesn't use XHR's onload

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

The following seems to work out.

```
var ajaxContext = $.ajax;
  $.ajax = function(options){

    var success = options.success;
    options.success = (function(data){
      data = data.Results;
      return success.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
    });

    return ajaxContext.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
  };
```